# How to set the tag correctly of ui element in uitableview- iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tags, element

I have a tableview controller, with a label and a switch displayed in a row. To add elements like this, I am using the approach below(as is recommended to avoid the data in the row getting mixed up).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         UISwitch* testSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:
                                     CGRectMake(200, 
                                                0.5 * (cell.frame.size.height-30 ), 
                                                30, 30)];
        testSwitch.tag = 2;//If this is a dynamic value, it only works for 14 rows
        [cell.contentView addSubview:testSwitch];
        [testSwitch release];
}
    UISwitch *switch1 = (UISwitch*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
//cannot set a dynamic value here
        switch1.on = [<array value> boolValue];
```

I need the tag to be a dynamic value depending on the data on the current row so that I can add an action method when the value changes, and make according model related changes. 
However, since the tag is set in the first section, if I make that dynamic, only 14 values(which are the number of rows displayed on the screen) are set. 
What do I do so that I can store a dynamic value on all the rows of this switch for its target action method to retrieve?

Thanks..

--Edit---
Changed code to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         UISwitch* testSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:
                                     CGRectMake(200, 
                                                0.5 * (cell.frame.size.height-30 ), 
                                                30, 30)];
        testSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;//If this is a dynamic value, it only works for 14 rows
        [cell.contentView addSubview:testSwitch];
        [testSwitch release];
}
    UISwitch *switch1 = (UISwitch*) [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];

    switch1.on = someboolValue; //CRASH as switch1 points to UItablviewcell and not UISwitch.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
testSwitch.tag=[indexPath row]
```

assuming you only have one section.

---

ok, it now sounds like you are having a problem that 
    [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]

is locating the cell and not it's subview so assuming you only have one uiswitch subview:

```
for (UIView *v in [cell subviews]) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) {
        v.on = someboolValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for some reason, its not working. Code is edited to the answer

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by taking the switch coding outside the if cell==nil code, and it seems to work ok .